# Comparing Tail Probabilities of Sum of Dominated Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-writing, normal-distribution, distribution-tails

I have been thinking about the following problem for quite a while, but did not get much progress of how to approach it:

Assume that

1. $X$, $Y$ are independent random variables with **N**(0, 1) distribution.
2. A and B are dependent bounded random variables: i.e., $|A|\leq a$ and $|B| \leq b$ for some fixed real number $a$ and $b$.
3. Moreover, $A$ and $B$ also have a dependence on $X$ and $Y$.

It is obvious that $ P(|aX|\geq M) \geq P(|AX|\geq M)  $ since $|aX|\geq |AX|$ almost surely.

I am interested in comparing the tail probabilities of the sum as follows.

Are there any "if and only if" type of conditons that 
$$ P(|aX+bY|\geq M) \geq P(|AX+BY|\geq M)  \ when \ M \rightarrow \infty$$

If so, we will have the tail dominance in the limit as M goes to infinity.

Many thanks!

Sean

Comment: Good question. What if $A \in \{-a, a\}$ and $B \in \{-b, b\}$ and $A=a$ if and only if $X>0$; $B=b$ if and only if $Y>0$.  Then we always have $$ AX+BY = |aX| + |bY| \geq |aX+bY|$$ and strict inequality holds quite frequently.  So the tail probability bound goes the other way, at least for finite $M$.

Comment: Yes, I was worried about that as well. Thank you so much for the reply. I was wonder if there is any reuslts on the necceasry and sufficient condtiions for the tail probabitty dominance to happen in such a case.